# Add document library to each users MySite

Tags: document-library, user-profile

Is there any way to customize each user profile on my SharePoint 2013 Enterprise edition in order to add a new section "CV" (A document library) that will be editable by a dedicated SharePoint group (Human resources in my case) and by the current mysites user.

Comment: any ideas????????

Comment: maybe it isn't possible...

Comment: Hey Robert, u have an idea?

Comment: I am confused, do you want a library of a User Profile Property? (Or a link to a document maintained by HR?) Can you expand your question with some details or a use case?

Comment: Thanks Matthew... (I'm french, sorry...) So I would like to find a way to add a CV file (word document) on each profile of my SharePoint site. This CV has to be accessible by a sharepoint or an LDAP group using the search engine... For example I'm an Human ressources guy 5i belong to HR group) and I want to know who have on his CV "sharepoint developper" skill... I search on the SharePoint site "sharepoint developper" and the result of the query give me a list of CV...

Comment: You should POC t and try creating a single library for all CV then add a field to the profile that links to the document. Create a display template that includes the link.